# Dropping column values that don't meet a requirement

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with a 'date_of_birth' column. Values take the form `1977-10-24T00:00:00.000Z` for example.

I want to grab the year, so I tried the following:

```
X['date_of_birth'] = X['date_of_birth'].apply(lambda x: int(str(x)[4:]))
```

This works if I am guaranteed that the first 4 letters are always integers, but it fails on my data set as some dates are messed up or garbage. Is there a way I can adjust my lambda without using regex? If not, how could I write this in regex?

Comment: You could just convert to datetime `df['date_of_birth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_birth'], errors='coerce')`  and then you can do `df['date_of_birth'].year`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be better to just use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime) to convert to `datetime` dtype, you can drop the invalid rows using [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna) and also access just the year attribute using [`dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html):

```
In [58]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['1977-10-24T00:00:00.000Z', 'duff', '200', '2016-01-01']})
df['mod_dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')
df

Out[58]:
                       date  mod_dates
0  1977-10-24T00:00:00.000Z 1977-10-24
1                      duff        NaT
2                       200        NaT
3                2016-01-01 2016-01-01

In [59]:    
df.dropna()

Out[59]:
                       date  mod_dates
0  1977-10-24T00:00:00.000Z 1977-10-24
3                2016-01-01 2016-01-01

In [60]:
df['mod_dates'].dt.year

Out[60]:
0    1977.0
1       NaN
2       NaN
3    2016.0
Name: mod_dates, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks @EdChum, short and concise.

Comment: I'd prefer this approach as you end up with a column you can perform proper work with and get full validation of dates. However,if one was really insistent to just taking 4 digits (and mostly for reference) then `df['date'].str.extract('^(\d{4})', expand=False).astype(float)` is a possibility...